# Build using TeamCity: Failed to start MSBuild; please specify a nuspec or project file to use

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm trying to build a website in Teamcity, but the first build step "starting MSBuild" is failing.It seems that the command is trying to install nuget, but it is complaining that there is *no nuspec or project file specified*.

I have a "nuget.targets" file and the code compiles fine outside of teamcity , so I think it must be a setting I am missing, and not a file I actually need to add but maybe I do need to add a nuspec or project file?  Assuming I do, how would I go about doing that?

```
[Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\61cf1fbc18b86c6f\.nuget\NuGet.targets
(109, 9): Please specify a nuspec or project file to use.
```

I am completely new to Teamcity (~3hrs); how do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If a build fails or behaves differntly in TeamCity than locally, then it is recommended to run the build in the working folder on agent machine under the same user that the agent is running. Find more details [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally).